# Multiple aggregations at same level with high-level java client Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

How to convert below dsl query with multiple aggregations at same level to java api using high-level java client?

```
{

"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "by_time": {
        "max": {
            "field": "updated_ts"
        }
    },
    "by_question": {
        "value_count": {
            "field": "questions.question.keyword"
        }
    },
    "by_score": {
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "score": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hi ,Try using this code if you are using ES version 6.8 or lesser***

```
        MaxAggregationBuilder by_time = AggregationBuilders
                .max("by_time")
                .field("updated_ts");

        ValueCountAggregationBuilder by_question = AggregationBuilders
                .count("by_question")
                .field("questions.question.keyword");

        ValueCountAggregationBuilder by_view = AggregationBuilders
                .count("by_view")
                .field("questions.viewStats.name.keyword");

        FilterAggregationBuilder by_score = AggregationBuilders
                .filter("by_score", QueryBuilders.termQuery("score",100));

        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        //Setting aggregation to search request
        sourceBuilder.aggregation(by_time);
        sourceBuilder.aggregation(by_question);
        sourceBuilder.aggregation(by_view);
        sourceBuilder.aggregation(by_score);
        //To avoid fetching docs
        sourceBuilder.size(0);

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.indices(MODEL_INDEX_NAME);
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        //For getting result from aggregations
        //Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_structuring_aggregations.html

        Max byTimeAggregationResult = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("by_time");
        double byTimeMaxValue = byTimeAggregationResult.getValue();

        ValueCount byQuestionAggregationResult = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("by_question");
        long byQuestionCount = byQuestionAggregationResult.getValue();

        ValueCount  byViewAggregationResult = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("by_view");
        long byViewCount = byViewAggregationResult.getValue();

        Filter byScoreAggregationResult = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("by_score");
        long byScoreDocCount = byScoreAggregationResult.getDocCount();

        System.out.println("byTimeMaxValue: "+byTimeMaxValue);
        System.out.println("byQuestionCount: "+byQuestionCount);
        System.out.println("byViewCount: "+byViewCount);
        System.out.println("byScoreDocCount: "+byScoreDocCount);
```